# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class with TeamCity build

Tags: java, android, ant, teamcity, classnotfoundexception

After adding android-support-v7-appcompat and google-play-services_lib to the Android project application starts to crash right after start with 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception.

I read all questions on StackOverflow related to this problem, and opened Eclipse -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export and verified that:
Android Private Libraries, Android dependencies, Google Play Services.jar are checked and Android API unchecked here. 
[image: All libs settings you can see here]

So apk built locally works fine. But on TeamCity side apk which we get as result crash with exception. So I suppose, that I need to add some changes to Ant script regarding android-support-v7-appcompat.

Please suggest steps which I can try.

Comment: Ensure your ant script have something about your new libs. Try to build project using ant on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException is exactly that. A class that is references cannot be found. When working with third party libraries, you must ensure that their dependancies (if any) are also included in your class path.

Without seeing the actual stacktrace, its difficult to narrow down the problem, but I would check if the dependancies of the third party libraries that I am adding are also included in the class path.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can provide stacktrace but I don't think that it contains any valuable data. Actually I am wondering why there is a difference between locally built apk and TeamCity. Maybe I should add additional steps to TeamCity because of adding android-support-v7-appcompat lib.