# Migrate from C2DM to GCM for Android SDK 19

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have an application for Android SDK 19, which is written for using C2DM. And I need to migrate it to GCM. I faced with next problems:

1. Actually there is no /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ folder. As I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776582/doesnt-exist-google-play-services-libproject-folder) it was replaced by Google Repository library and split into different parts
2. GCM located into obsolete library [Google Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589912/the-import-com-google-android-gms-gcm-googlecloudmessaging-cannot-be-resolved)
3. I have some google-play-services_lib (downloaded from somewhere android:versionCode="3265130" android:versionName="3.2.65 (834000-30)" uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8") but when I try to import this library into project I receive [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error after build on TeamCity side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475591/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-with-teamcity-build)

The questions are:

1. Is there is a possibility to use old google-play-services_lib under new Android OS if I include this old lib into my project?
2. Is there is a possible way to use GCM by using old google-play-services_lib?
3. What I do wrong with importing google-play-services_lib?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to follow this guide 
Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/

I think that this guide is very useful and helpful.

Comment: the firebase link you shared is for firebase legacy console which is a older version of firebase. new link https://firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

instead of using GCM try to migrate to firebase

google now recommends to use firebase notification

https://firebase.google.com/